# How to run a program without the command window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyinstaller

I need to run my program without the standard command window. I know that the standard `print()` and `input()` functions will no longer work. I am compiling the program with `pyinstaller`. My exact command is `python -m pyinstaller --onefile <filename>.py` Is there a way so that only my GUI shows up when I run the program? Thanks to whoever answers.

Edit: I have tried to run the program using another program I wrote and compiled, but I still see a window.

Comment: Do you try : `python -m pyinstaller --noconsole yourscript.py`

Comment: OMG IT WORKS `python -m pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile myscript.py` WORKS!

Comment: I will put that in an answer so future users can find it quickly. Please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exact answer to your question but there is an option in windows when you schedule a task in task-scheduler, you can keep the command window hidden while running the program. Try having a look there..

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for. What I need is to load the executable from my thumb drive onto another computer then to be able to run it anytime instead of having a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Try `python -m pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile yourscript.py`
It compiles without a window.

Comment: I would accept this answer, but I can't until 2 days later. So to everyone who comes, just letting you know that this answer is the one I am accepting.